# Frequencies in two areas

Tags: calculus, probability

Okay, so this is almost certainly really frigging stupid, but my brain's not working.

Say we have two areas, A and B, of different sizes and they each have red and blue marbles in. I want to calculate the total frequency of the red marbles.

Say area A is 10 square meters, area B is 1 square meter.

Area A has 100 red marbles, and 500 blue marbles; Area B has 10 red marbles, and 25 blue marbles.

So the frequencies respectively are: `f(A) = 100/600 = 1/6`, `f(B)=10/35=0.285...`.

Now the frequency of the total area is: `f(T) = 110 / 635 = 0.1732283`.

But why can't I do:

```
f(T) = f(A) * 10/11 + f(B) * 1 / 11 = 0.1774892
```

Please could someone help me see what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain where you're getting the denominator of 11? I see it as $600/635\cdot f(A) + 35/635\cdot f(B)$ which agrees with the given answer.

Comment: From the total area. But I think I follow - if we just knew the frequency and the areas we couldn't work out the total frequency. We'd need to know the density of both areas as well... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the frequency is the specific ratio over total number of marbles in each area, so if you want to get $f(T)$ using $f(A) * weight_A + f(B) * weight_B$, then the weights must be the ratio of total number as well, which is $$
f(T) = f(A) * \frac{n_a}{n} + f(B) * \frac{n_b}{n}=\frac{100}{600}*\frac{600}{635} + \frac{10}{35}*\frac{35}{635}
$$
you can get the identical result.